# Get User Location from Graph API

Tags: android

This is what I'm trying to do currently

```
    permissions.add("user_friends");
    permissions.add("email");
    permissions.add("public_profile");
    permissions.add("user_location");
```

Also in my Bundle I'm passing the argument

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("fields", "id,name,picture,cover,email,location,accounts");
```

Unfortunately the Response does not contain the location object.

Even tried this Approach but crashes as response is null or some error

```
new GraphRequest(
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
"/me?fields=location",
null,
HttpMethod.GET,
new GraphRequest.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        /* handle the result */
    }
}
).executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Many months later I know, but for anyone that may need it here is what worked for me:

```
 @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                    URL profile_pic=null;
                    try
                    {

                        String id = object.getString("id"); // get_id
                        try {
                            profile_pic = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?width=150&height=150");
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        String pic = profile_pic.toString(); //get profile pic to string to decode later to bitmap if needed
                        String name = object.getString("name"); // get username
                        String email = object.getString("email"); //get user email

                        String location = object.getJSONObject("location").getString("name");  //get location


                        System.out.println(id + ", " + name + ", " + email + " " + location);
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(StartingActivity.this, SignUpFinalise.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
```

the logic here is that location in the response object is an object itself. therefore need to call getJSONObject on it so we can go deeper in its tree and get the "name" field which is the actual location
You can see an example of the response object here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph